# I have renamed "/usr" folder in Ubuntu, now trying to rename to "/usr", but I have problems I think because "/usr" folder does not exist

Tags: bash, filesystem, directory, mv, inode

I have tryed to restoresome data and moved "usr" folder in Ubuntu.
For any command I tr, for example "mv", "cp", the system writing "/usr-new/bin/mv: cannot execute: required file not found" (/usr-new is I copy of /usr folder, i have extended PATH enviroment variable to link to there also when I was trying to solve it), escept builtin commands (like "cd", "set", "pwd"). All I want is to move (rename) folder "usr-copy" to "usr", I have all the data. I have no much time (it is interesting for me) to solve this problem. I don't know what is fastest solution.
Operating system: "Ububtu (Version 22, Probably, I have not access to it to find out exact version number)".
Thank You in advance!
I'am scared to inform system administrator, he gave me responsibility, when gave "root" rights to it.

I was trying to find reason of such answer ("/usr-new/bin/mv: cannot execute: required file not found"), learn how to rename (only change the link of the folder "inode") files using only builin commands, tryed to disasemble "/usr/bin/bash" file to learn in code, why it can be

Comment: Use Busybox, it should still work.